# KeyError: '\\documentclass'

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following Python script:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
nltk.download('punkt')

frequencies = {}
book = open('book.txt')
read_book = book.read()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(read_book)
frequencyDist = FreqDist(words)

for w in words:
    frequencies[w] = frequencies[w] + 1 

print (frequencies)
```

When I try to run the script, I get the following:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/abc/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    frequencies[w] = frequencies[w] + 1 
KeyError: '\\documentclass'
```

What am I doing wrong? And, how can I print the word and the number of times it occurs in the text file.

You can download `book.txt`, from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q0e555464nia7w/book.txt?dl=1).

Comment: Why do you have `frequencies` and your buggy loop over `words` when you're also using an NLTK `FreqDist` that contains all the information you're trying to obtain?

Comment: The very first time through your loop, you're attempting to fetch `frequencies[w]`, which does not (yet) exist.  So you get a key error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `frequencies` dictionary is empty. You get key error right from the start, that is expected.

I suggest that you use `collections.Counter` instead. It is a specialized dictionary (a bit like `defaultdict`) which allows to count occurrences.

```
import nltk,collections
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
nltk.download('punkt')

frequencies = collections.Counter()
with open('book.txt') as book:
    read_book = book.read()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(read_book)
frequencyDist = FreqDist(words)

for w in words:
    frequencies[w] += 1 

print (frequencies)
```

EDIT: That answers your question without using `ntlk` package at all. I answered just like `nltk` package was just a string tokenizer. So to be more specific and allow to go further in your text analysis without reinventing the wheel, and thanks to the various comments below, you should just do this:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
nltk.download('punkt')

with open('book.txt') as book:
    read_book = book.read()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(read_book)
frequencyDist = FreqDist(words)   # no need for the loop, does the count job

print (frequencyDist)
```

you'll get (with my text):

```
<FreqDist with 142 samples and 476 outcomes>
```

so not a dictionary with word => number of elements directly, but a more complex object bearing this information + a lot more:

- `frequencyDist.items()`: you get the words=>count (and all classical dict methods)
- `frequencyDist.most_common(50)` prints the 50 most common words
- `frequencyDist['the']` returns the number of occurrences of `"the"`
- ...

Comment: Instead of using a `collections.Counter`, I'd recommend using that `FreqDist` that gets built and then completely ignored. It's basically a `Counter` with a few extra NLTK utilities attached to it.

Comment: @user2357112 you're probably right. I was fixing the OP issue from a basic python point of view. You should post an answer using `FreqDist`. I cannot talk about it as I don't know `nltk`. I suppose the OP copied some code from somewhere and doesn't know all `nltk` possibilities.

Comment: The real answer is that `frequencyDist` is not `frequencies` or vice versa, he made a count, it works but he doesn't call it, hes calling an empty dict.

Comment: @MooingRawr sounds right. I'll experiment with ntlk. Don't hesitate to answer. My answer (which seems to be appreciated because of the `Counter` generic usefulness) is not specific enough for the OP problem (at least the OP _next_ problem). I'm sorry if I answered like a python-bot :)

Comment: I'm not going to submit an answer, since you are on the right path, just fix yours xD

Comment: The `FreqDist` instance already contains all the counts when it's initialized as `FreqDist(words)`. The loop is unnecessary; it just ends up erroneously doubling all the counts (or perhaps doing nothing if `words` is an iterator and `FreqDist(words)` already consumed it).

Comment: If you want to print the `FreqDist` as if it were a dict, to see all the information it encodes, you can do `print(dict(frequencyDist))`.

Comment: @user2357112 right! It actually doubles it. I'm more and more under the impression I'm stealing your answer... Edited.